# How to print large and complex files without upgrading printer memory

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer

I have a `HP LaserJet P2055d` printer. Printer memory is `64 MB` and printer processor speed `600 MHz`. Printing large documents containing scanned images and complex vector objects takes a long time. Is there anyway to process the print job using computer hardware not the printer hardware without the need to upgrade the printer memory?

Comment: I have heard that using something called `ghostscript` this can be done but I do not have more information about it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript Ghostscript

Comment: In general, adding more memory does NOT speed up printers. Your best bet will be to reduce the size of the job, possiblyby reducing the dpi of the images (200-300 dpi on the paper is all you need). How large are the spool files?

Comment: @hdhondt The size of spool file for 2 A4 pages of a 300 dpi scanned picture is `36MB`.

Comment: Dear @hdhondt  as it has been mentioned [here](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/327439/how_speed_up_your_printer/) and [here](http://technology.blurtit.com/111581/how-the-printing-speed-can-be-increase),  increasing the memory of LaserJet printers may increase the speed of the printer.

Comment: I have to disagree. Except under very special circumstances (e.g. very old printers that use memory compression, or for collating large docs), adding memory for speed does nothing more than waste money. A printer is not like a PC, it is a pipeline that takes in a command from the interface, processes it to produce dots on the paper, and then takes the next command. Memory does nothing for that. You can test it if you like, by buying some... Try scanning the documents at 200 dpi. Or try using the PostScript driver instead of PCL.

Comment: @hdhondt Is PostScript better that PCL?

Comment: PostScript is not "better", unless you are into desktop publishing. However, with PCL, the higher the printer resolution, the more image data you have to send. With PS, the printer up/downscales the image resolution as required. Hence, for a 600dpi printer, you still only need to send a 200dpi image. Note that the driver handles all this. Either way, scanning at 200dpi is fine, 300dpi should be the max - unless you print larger than the scan. An A4 colour image at 300dpi should be about 3MB, so 36MB certainly seems high.

Comment: Dear @hdhondt Thank you. I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Rasterize the vector graphics
- Convert colors to 8-bit grayscale
- Use two-sided printing and draft mode
- Use USB rather than ethernet

```
Image Type               Bytes per pixel
1 bit Line art           1/8 byte per pixel(1 bit per pixel, 8 bits per byte)
8 bit Grayscale          1 byte per pixel
16 bit Grayscale         2 bytes per pixel
24 bit RGB               3 bytes per pixel(Most common for photos, for example JPG)
32 bit CMYK              4 bytes per pixel, for Prepress
48 bit RGB               6 bytes per pixel
```

**References**

- [Color, Bit-Depth, and Memory Cost of Images](http://www.scantips.com/basics1d.html)
- [Digital Formats for Content Reproductions](http://memory.loc.gov/ammem/formats.html)
- [HP LaserJet P2050 Series Printer:Software Technical Reference (pdf)](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01557595)
- [Details of Ghostscript output devices](http://vis.lbl.gov/NERSC/Software/ghostview/docs/Devices.htm)